# How to create a custom command utility

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npm-scripts

I want to create a custom command in node.js, like `create-react-app`  please share me the details,if i run that command in node terminal it should create some directroy and files like create-react-app dose
so that i can run that command like this

```
->cutsom_command myapp
```

Comment: What have you tried?  What have you researched yourself?  Where did you get stuck?  There are all sorts of file manipulation functions in the `fs` module in node.js.  You can use them to do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to kickstart a new projects with the same set of packages, try using [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io). It will be much easier to use it instead of writing your utility from ground up.